# satistical on filtered data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to apply statistical on filtered data, but its not working...

My Scenario is:

I want to apply statistical on some filtered data. So i applied the following query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10000,
  "facets": {
    "stats": {
      "statistical": {
        "field": "xxxx"
      },"facet_filter": {
        "and": [
            {
              "term": {
                "id_1": "33"
              }
            }
          ],
          "or": [
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "aaaa"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "bbbb"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Its working Fine. But when i apply on multiple fields its not working.The following is the query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10000,
  "facets": {
    "stats": {
      "statistical": {
        "field": "xxxx"
      },"facet_filter": {
          "and": [
            {
              "term": {
                "id_1": "33"
              }
            }
          ],
          "or": [
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "aaaa"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "bbbb"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    },
    "stats1": {
      "statistical": {
        "field": "yyyy"
      },"facet_filter": {
          "and": [
            {
              "term": {
                "id_1": "33"
              }
            }
          ],
          "or": [
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "aaaa"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "bbbb"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

It throws following error:

```
Parse Failure [No parser for element [stats1]]]; }]",
   "status": 400
```

Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your filters are identical for facetA and facetB you can pull them up above the facets so that you have a filter that applies to ALL facets.

Comment: I would use the [aggregations API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html), I think they're trying to phase out facets.

Comment: @ jhilden thanks for your time. My FIlter is identical so can you please explain little bit more.. Statistical is  not applying on filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have your facet filters set up uses incorrect syntax, nor do they make logical sense, since you have an `"and"` and an `"or"` at the same level. This is the reason for your error. I'm assuming that what you meant was this, with the `"or"` inside the `"and"`:

```
     "facet_filter": {
        "and": [
           {
              "term": {
                 "id_1": "33"
              }
           },
           {
              "or": [
                 {
                    "term": {
                       "type": "aaaa"
                    }
                 },
                 {
                    "term": {
                       "type": "bbbb"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        ]
     }
```

Furthermore, since your filter is the same in both cases, you may as well use it in a filtered query so you only have to specify it once. Using that, I got the following toy example to work as I assume you're wanting:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   }
}

POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":1}}
{"id_1":"32", "xxxx":2, "yyyy":5,"type":"aaaa"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":2}}
{"id_1":"32", "xxxx":3, "yyyy":10,"type":"bbbb"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":3}}
{"id_1":"33", "xxxx":4, "yyyy":15,"type":"aaaa"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":4}}
{"id_1":"33", "xxxx":5, "yyyy":20,"type":"bbbb"}


POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "and": [
               {
                  "term": {
                     "id_1": "33"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "or": [
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "type": "aaaa"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "type": "bbbb"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "facets": {
      "stats": {
         "statistical": {
            "field": "xxxx"
         }
      },
      "stats1": {
         "statistical": {
            "field": "yyyy"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "facets": {
      "stats": {
         "_type": "statistical",
         "count": 2,
         "total": 9,
         "min": 4,
         "max": 5,
         "mean": 4.5,
         "sum_of_squares": 41,
         "variance": 0.25,
         "std_deviation": 0.5
      },
      "stats1": {
         "_type": "statistical",
         "count": 2,
         "total": 35,
         "min": 15,
         "max": 20,
         "mean": 17.5,
         "sum_of_squares": 625,
         "variance": 6.25,
         "std_deviation": 2.5
      }
   }
}
```

Having said that, you probably will be better off using aggregations, especially since facets are now deprecated. The same example with a [stats aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-stats-aggregation.html) looks like this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "and": [
               {
                  "term": {
                     "id_1": "33"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "or": [
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "type": "aaaa"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "type": "bbbb"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "stats": {
         "stats": {
            "field": "xxxx"
         }
      },
      "stats1": {
         "stats": {
            "field": "yyyy"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "stats": {
         "count": 2,
         "min": 4,
         "max": 5,
         "avg": 4.5,
         "sum": 9
      },
      "stats1": {
         "count": 2,
         "min": 15,
         "max": 20,
         "avg": 17.5,
         "sum": 35
      }
   }
}
```

Or you could use an [extended stats aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-extendedstats-aggregation.html) if you want:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "and": [
               {
                  "term": {
                     "id_1": "33"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "or": [
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "type": "aaaa"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "type": "bbbb"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "stats": {
         "extended_stats": {
            "field": "xxxx"
         }
      },
      "stats1": {
         "extended_stats": {
            "field": "yyyy"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "stats": {
         "count": 2,
         "min": 4,
         "max": 5,
         "avg": 4.5,
         "sum": 9,
         "sum_of_squares": 41,
         "variance": 0.25,
         "std_deviation": 0.5
      },
      "stats1": {
         "count": 2,
         "min": 15,
         "max": 20,
         "avg": 17.5,
         "sum": 35,
         "sum_of_squares": 625,
         "variance": 6.25,
         "std_deviation": 2.5
      }
   }
}
```